# Report (RDLC) not fitting to fullscreen reportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, rdlc

I'm having a lot of "fun" trying to get my report to fill the browser's screen.

The report viewer fits to the screen but the underlying report does not follow.

Here's what I've tried:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    List<SchoolViewModel> res = BLL.Reports.ReportMethods.GetSchool();

    ReportViewer1.Reset();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports/SchoolReport.rdlc";
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SchoolDS", res));
    ReportViewer1.AsyncRendering = false; // Force inline/remove iFrame
    ReportViewer1.SizeToReportContent = true; // Fit report to screen
    ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage;
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

And the markup:

```
<form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
            Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)"
            WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="100%" style="width:100%;">
            <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\SchoolReport.rdlc"></LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>

        <div class="backButtonWrapper">
            <a id="backButton" href="../home">Go back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does the report have a fixed width/height defined in the rdlc file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add SizeToReportContent = true in the rsweb:reportviewer tag.

For example:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" AsyncRendering="false" ProcessingMode="Remote" SizeToReportContent="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code .

```
 ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ZoomMode.PageWidth;
```

I think it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

ReportViewer full screen is only supported in Interet Explorer and even then it is a bit flakey. If you really want it try this:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1771258.aspx